# Excel VBA eval string to variable

Tags: excel, vba, evaluate

Is there any way use excel vba can this?

```
Dim Var1 as integer
eval("var1=1")
msgbox var1,   'resault 1

Dim Var1 as integer,Var2 as string
Var2="Var1"
eval(Var2)=1
msgbox Var1 'rsault 1
```

Comment: Not prettily. Why are you trying to do this?

Comment: Try to save some typing and curious.  thank you for reply

Comment: You might look into a `Scripting.Dictionary` here... not sure what your end goal is, but a hunch.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can just do this.  You don't have to Evaluate var1=1, you can put that expression straight into the box.  These 3 message boxes give you True, False, and True.

```
Sub test()

var1 = 1
MsgBox var1 = 1

var1 = 2
MsgBox var1 = 1


x = Evaluate(var1 = 2)
MsgBox x

End Sub
```